# reference_wrapper to abstract class serialization in boost

Tags: serialization, boost, reference-wrapper

I must serialize in Boost vector (or any other container) of abstract class.
Because it is impossible to create vector of abstract class directly, I created vector of reference_wrapper's to this abstract class.

But how to serialize in Boost std::reference_wrapper to abstract class? When I try to do it directly, I get an error, that default constructor of reference_wrapper is inaccessible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you care to create a MCVE?

Comment: No, what is MCVE? How to create it? I can't find any info about it in google.

Comment: Ok. I was trying to be hip and [get with the times](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 2):

Thinking some more about this you wouldn't want to serialize the references.

Since logically references are non-reseatable, and don't "hold any data", they could never be "deserialized" (what would they point to? temporaries? leaked heap objects?).

Of course `reference_wrappers` *are* reseatable, but in that case you're *really* just using them as raw pointers (potentially owning pointers).

In that case, just have them serialized as pointers and optionally use object tracking to prevent duplicate (de)serialization.

> ***Hint** I think you'd benefit from `boost::ptr_vector` which comes with serialization support built in. See below (and [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html))*

---

### Demo

While coming up with a simple approach that "teaches" Boost Serialization to use `reference_wrapper` just as a raw pointer (which is *likely* what you require):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/294b89a38cddfae5)</kbd>**

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Allow serialization of `reference_wrapper`
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template<class Ar, class T> void save_construct_data(Ar & ar, std::reference_wrapper<T> const * t, unsigned) {
        T const * p = &t->get();
        ar << p;
    }
    template<class Ar, class T> void load_construct_data(Ar & ar, std::reference_wrapper<T> * t, unsigned) {
        T* p = nullptr;
        ar >> p;
        ::new(t) std::reference_wrapper<T>(*p);
    }

    template <class Ar, typename T> inline void serialize(Ar &, std::reference_wrapper<T>&, unsigned) { }
} }
```

However, I found out that there's a bigger problem with the fact that `reference_wrapper` isn't default-constructible wreaks havoc with the way std::vector is deserialized.

I'd simplify and just use pointers when you mean pointers:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7ec6b952f411bdf)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

#include <boost/ptr_container/serialize_ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <functional>

using namespace boost;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// defining a virtual class hierarchy...
struct B {
    virtual ~B() = default;
    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const { return os << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; }

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar&, unsigned) const {
    }
};

struct D1 : B {
    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const { return os << _data; }

  private:
    std::string _data = "forty two";

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<B>(*this);
        ar & _data;
    }
};

struct D2 : B {
    virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const { return os << _data; }

  private:
    int _data = 42;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<B>(*this);
        ar & _data;
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(B)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(D1)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(D2)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// sample data structure representing our program

struct Data {
    ptr_vector<B> storage;
    std::vector<B*> refvect;

    void fill_sample() {
        storage.push_back(new D1);
        storage.push_back(new D1);
        storage.push_back(new D2);
        storage.push_back(new D1);

        refvect.clear();
        for (auto it = storage.rbegin(); it != storage.rend(); ++it)
            refvect.push_back(&*it);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Data const& data) {
        for (auto i : data.refvect) i->print(std::cout) << "\n";
        return os;
    }

    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar & storage & refvect;
    }
};

#include <sstream>
int main() {

    std::stringstream stream;
    {
        archive::binary_oarchive oa(stream);

        Data x;
        x.fill_sample();
        oa << x;

        std::cout << "Before:\n" << x << "\n";
    }

    {
        archive::binary_iarchive ia(stream);

        Data y;
        ia >> y;
        std::cout << "After:\n" << y << "\n";
    }

}
```

Prints

```
Before:
forty two
42
forty two
forty two

After:
forty two
42
forty two
forty two
```